# Omega 4 LiveReload auto refresh browser issue

Tags: theming

I am on a Windows desktop developing remotely on a linux server. [LiveReload](https://www.drupal.org/project/livereload) does not make any changes without refreshing the browser.

The default **LiveReload settings** are as follows, do I need to change them?

- Script: URL `http://localhost:35729/livereload.js`
- Host: localhost
- Port: 35729

Answer (score 0):

Yes - they need to reflect the location of the server you are looking at.  SO, if you access the website with x.y.com in your web browser, that's what you need to say in that setting.